# Finding power of a number giving irrelevant answer. Can anyone give me the reason?

Tags: java, algorithm

Finding the power of a number using java.

if the input takes 5 and 9 as input it produces irrelevant answer.

```
import java.util.* ;
import java.io.*; 
class Solution {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        // Write code here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println((n==0)?1:findPower(x,n));    
    }
    static int findPower(int x,int n){
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            x*=x;
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

[Screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln4Kt.png)

Comment: Try to learn debugging, it will help you to find problems like this.

Comment: Do not tag `dsa`.  Your question has nothing to do with Digital Signature Algorithm.

Comment: DSA refers to Data Structures and Algorithms and not Digital Signature Algorithm.

Comment: @Anselum -- Please read what the tags are before you apply them.   Here at StackOverflow, DSA means Digital Signature Algorithm. -- *DSA (Digital Signature Algorithm) is a public-key signature algorithm defined by NIST. Do NOT use this tag for general "Data Structures and Algorithms" questions.*.  Anyone who has subscribed to the `dsa` tag now has to see your question which has nothing to do with the Digital Signature Algorithm topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are squaring the input `n` times instead of multiplying the input `n` times. You can start the result at `1`, then keep multiplying it by `x` in the loop.

```java
int res = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) res *= x;
return res;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Finding power of a number giving irrelevant answer. Can anyone give me the reason?

By putting in a print statement you can see what is happening.

```
 int n = 9, x = 5;
 for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
     System.out.printf("%12d = %12d * %12d%n", x*x, x, x);
     x = x * x;
 }
```

prints (Since you asked for a reason, the ints are overflowing, resulting in negative values).

```
          25 =            5 *            5
         625 =           25 *           25
      390625 =          625 *          625
 -2030932031 =       390625 *       390625
 -2052264063 =  -2030932031 *  -2030932031
 -1083564287 =  -2052264063 *  -2052264063
   781532673 =  -1083564287 *  -1083564287
 -1741784063 =    781532673 *    781532673
   -59967487 =  -1741784063 *  -1741784063
```

You are multiplying the number by itself each time.  Just initialize an `int result` value to `1` and multiply it using `result = result * x;`

You can also use streams.

```
int n = 9, x = 5;
int result = IntStream.range(0,n).reduce(1, (a,b)->a*x);
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
1953125
```